# How does this integral change due to restricted x values?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

So, I integrated this integral: $$I = \int\frac{dx}{(x^2+4)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
And got: $$I = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\arctan{\frac{x\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}}+C$$
But, since $-1 < x < 1$, how does it affect the integral?

Comment: The domain condition doesn't affect the indefinite integral. However, if you were to try using your result with a definite integral you'd need to make sure that the bounds satisfy your domain conditions.

Comment: I asked this because, in my workbook, it says the solution above is only for $0 < x < 1$ and for $-1 < x < 0$ it is: $$I=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\arctan{\frac{x\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}}+C$$ Why do we change the sign?

Comment: hey!, the integrate function is even! do you remember the relation between the derivate for $x<0$ and $x>0$?

Comment: I'm not sure, please explain. I'm really confused with even/odd thing and what derivative tells us.

Comment: So, our function is even and the returns same values for -x and x. So, how does it affect our restriction and why do we change sign, still confused :(

Comment: I actually did it very similarly to WA, like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/utvuv.jpg and look what WA does in the last step, it really confuses me.